# Android native library for Visual Studio 2015(xamarin)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android

i'm trying to make android project based on native library(.so).
the problem is i don't know how to add libraries to project.
I have  tried to do as analogous to Android Studio just add lib folder with armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86 versions, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mono Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/):

Add the native library to the project and set its `BuildAction` property to "AndroidNativeLibrary" or "EmbeddedNativeLibrary" depending on your project type.

The architecture is determined by "sniffing" the path (see documentation link), or by explicit declaration in the project file with:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AndroidNativeLibrary Include="path/to/libfoo.so">
        <Abi>armeabi</Abi>
    </AndroidNativeLibrary>
</ItemGroup>
```

Actually using the native library is much more complex, but is documented [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/).

Comment: now apk contains libraries but it doesn't work.
when i call functions from library app crushes.

Comment: That part I can't really help you with, sorry.  I've never actually used a native library myself.